# Use SELECT output variables in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and have come across an issue where I can't retrieve additional data from a second stored procedure.

I am trying to retrieve data from two tables at once. The `person` table has a guid which references to the row in the `personname` table. I need all of the information from both tables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [database].[rsp_person_getitembyid]
    @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
    SELECT 'Person' AS TableName, * 
    FROM person 
    WHERE Id = @Id;

    EXEC [database].rsp_personname NameId;
```

The inside of **rsp_personname** is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [database].[rsp_personname]
    @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS

    SELECT 'PersonName' AS TableName, * 
    FROM crm_personname WHERE Id = @Id
```

The error I'm getting is

> Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier.

I think it is coming from `NameId` on the final line. The NameId and Id is stored as Guid in both tables.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you remove the `EXEC [database].rsp_personname NameId;` does the stored procedure execute successfully?

Comment: Yes, It works fine without it.

Comment: Can you post the source for [database].rsp_personname?

Comment: I've updated the post now to contain `rsp_personname`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be storing the `NameId` on a variable, and then using it to call the next sp:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [database].[rsp_person_getitembyid]
@Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS

DECLARE @NameId nvarchar(100);

SELECT @NameId = NameId
FROM person 
WHERE Id = @Id;

EXEC [database].rsp_personname @NameId;
```

**UPDATE**

I don't really understand what you want. Seems like a simple `JOIN`  would be enough:

```
SELECT *
FROM person p
INNER JOIN crm_personname pn
    ON p.Id = pn.Id
WHERE p.Id = @Id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would also need to get all of the other fields as well as the NameId column.

Comment: @SamBunting Then you should post what it is that you actually want to get in your question.

Comment: @SamBunting I'm not really clear about what you want, but updated my answer with what I understood

Comment: I've ended up doing it a different way of using parent id's now. I'll accept your answer anyways as it did work, and it will probably help more people who see this.